# Python Eve 0.8: how to perform a $geowithin with a $centerSphere?

Tags: python, mongodb, eve

We have deployed a docker container in which we have a MongoDB database running. This is a simple database in which we store geo-referenced sensor data (e.g. temperature, windspeed). Since we want to query these geo-referenced observations based in a search radius, we have enabled the spatial queries like this:

```
db.ObsStationTemp.createIndex({point:"2dsphere"})
db.ObsStationTemp.ensureIndex({"geometry":'2dsphere'})
```

The data is correctly ingested in MongoDB and we can actually perform the spatial query like:

```
db.ObsStationTemp.find({geometry:{$geoWithin:{$centerSphere:[[4.925922,51.969035],2/3963.2]}}})
```

Now we want to access these observations from an HTTP interface using Eve. We translated the previous query to HTTP. We have tried many combinations, such as:

```
 http://127.0.0.1:5000/ObsStationTemp?where={"geometry": {"$geoWithin": {"$centerSphere": [ [4.92592, 51.969035],0.02]}}}
```

But none of them works.
This is the reply of the Eve server:

```
{
   "_status": "ERR",
   "_error": {
       "code": 400,
       "message": "Query contains unknown or unsupported operators: $centerSphere"
   }
}
```

What are we missing in the current HTTP query? Any help or share an example? We are using Eve 0.8 and the query is performed using PostMan. Thanks.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> We are using Eve 0.8 and the query is performed using PostMan.

This is because [PyEve](http://python-eve.org/) (currently version 0.8) does not support the [$centerSphere](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/query/centerSphere/) operator. See [eve/io/mongo/mongo.py#L94-L102](https://github.com/pyeve/eve/blob/v0.8/eve/io/mongo/mongo.py#L94-L102). You may submit a request on [PyEve's issue tracker](https://github.com/pyeve/eve/issues) for the operator support.

Additional, worth noting that the use of `$geoWithin` with `$centerSphere` is only available on MongoDB v3.4+.

Comment: Thanks a lot! Following your recommendation, I opened a new issue here: https://github.com/pyeve/eve/issues/1181

Comment: `$centerSphere` support has been added to Eve v0.8.1-dev.

Comment: Thanks for merging my PR so quickly @NicolaIarocci